# Why did the board vote for David Brent over Neil when the branches are merging?

Tags: the-office-uk

<sub>***Note:*** This is about The Office (UK)</sub>

---

In [S01E06](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-office-uk&episode=s01e06) ("Judgement") of the Office UK, there is discussion about the Slough and Swindon branches merging.  The following conversation occurs between Jennifer and David Brent:

> **[Jennifer]** The point is, my job is now available and the board thought that you
> or Neil should do it. I can tell you the board have voted 5-2 in
> favour of you taking it.
>
> **[David]** Voted for me 5-2? There's only seven on the board. Five out of seven. That's a landslide.

David ends up accepting Jennifer's job, which means that the Slough staff will lose their jobs, but David will get a promotion and move to Swindon (he ends up not getting the job after he fails the health check, but that happens later).

We don't meet Neil until season 2, but when we do it's clear that he's a lot more competent and popular than David.  So, why did the board vote for David when it clearly wouldn't be good for the business?  It seems very out of character for Jennifer to even recommend David, based on her subsequent tough dealings with him in season 2.

My only thought is that it was a strategic move to save the Swindon staff from redundancy, and then terminate David later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We, the audience, know exactly what the workers at the Slough branch think of David Brent and his management style, but what we don't know is the board's perception of him and his abilities. Remember, unlike his staff, they do not interact with him on a daily basis, and will be judging him more-or-less solely by how well the Slough branch as a whole performs.

We do learn that the Slough branch performs well, and while the audience can surmise that this is in spite of David's management style rather than because of it, the board members are unlikely to be able to perceive this. Given that, they may well be perfectly happy with David's performance as branch manager and feel he will do a good job as regional manager.

Another possibility is that the board are well aware that David is a terrible manager (of people) and decide to take the opportunity to move him into a role where his day-to-day responsibilities won't involve quite so much interaction with the workers on the ground, in order to reduce friction and mitigate any negative effects of his behaviour on the rest of the staff. Neil on the other hand is a good man manager and is liked and respected by his staff, so they may well have felt that he would be the better man to run a large team of people.

A third possibility is that the Wernham Hogg boardroom is a bit of a boys' club populated by people who actually like David and get on with him, and therefore simply voted for him to get the job because they preferred him to Neil.

Finally, there is the good old [Peter Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_principle), which states that within a hierarchy people end up getting promoted based on their competence in a particular role until they reach the point of incompetence, because the skills they have which make them good for one role do not necessarily make them good at another type of role. It may well be that David Brent was a great paper salesman who ended up becoming branch manager via the Peter Principle, and nearly became regional manager via the same mechanism. We know from the [David Brent: Life on the Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Brent:_Life_on_the_Road) movie that he ended up going back into sales when he left Wernham Hogg, which indicates that he may have some natural talent in this area.

Comment: I should qualify that all of the above is my best guess based on working in the UK for companies that are comparable in size and structure as Wernham Hogg.